# How to fit lm model with user-supplied intercept

Tags: r, regression, linear-model

I'm trying to input the results from my Unobserved Component Model (`time_series_df$s_level`) into my linear regression model as the intercept. I've found two methods of doing so:

```
lm(y ~ 0 + x, offset = time_series_df$s_level, data=data_source))
lm(formula = I(y - time_series_df$s_level) ~ 0 + x, data = data_source)
```

Both of these lm models produce the same results (same coefficient for the x variable), however after running `summary()` on both of them I see that they produce completely different adjusted r squared values. Which is the correct way to specify your own intercept while ensuring that `lm()` doesn't supply its own intercept?

Comment: Have you tried plotting the predictions? You should be able to see from the plots which method is more correct. Do the models have the same amount of coefficients, could one of the models be calculating one variable too little because adjusted R-squared is calculated using the amount of coefficients as an input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get different r squared values because the response values are on different scales. So which one to use depends on whether it makes sense to interpret the error in terms of the subtracted values, or the raw values.

We can use an example dataset to show the difference, in the first model, it is on the same scale as your y:

```
set.seed(111)
df = data.frame(x=rep(1:10,2),
y=c(5+2*rep(1:10),10+3*rep(1:10))+rpois(20,2),
s_level=rep(c(5,10),each=10))

fit1 = lm(y~0+x,offset=s_level,data=df)
plot(df$x,df$y)
points(df$x,fitted(fit1),pch=20,cex=0.6,col="blue")
```

[image]

If you deduct it from y in the 2nd model, it is on the level of your subtracted y-value (take note of the y-axis numbers):

```
fit2 = lm(I(y - s_level) ~ 0 + x,data=df)
plot(df$x,df$y - df$s_level)
points(df$x,fitted(fit2),pch=20,cex=0.6,col="blue")
```

[image]